# What times can unique items be found?

Tags: pandoras-tower

In Pandora's Tower, each tower has a unique item that can only be found at certain times of the day.  When talking with Mavda after finishing a tower, she will give you a hint about the tower you just returned from.

The problem is, she doesn't give you specific times to go hunting.  She gives times of day, like morning, evening, or night.

So, the question is, what times of day reference what hours in the day?  Or, alternatively, in the event that each tower has a different set of hours to find each unique item, what are those hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the FAQ](http://translate.google.ca/translate?hl=en&sl=ja&u=http://wiki.grovyle.net/pandora/&ei=SPGZT7CxM4Tg2QW47qzvDg&sa=X&oi=translate&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCMQ7gEwAA&prev=/search%3Fq%3Dhttp://wiki.grovyle.net/pandora/%26hl%3Den%26client%3Dfirefox-a%26rls%3Dorg.mozilla:en-US:official%26biw%3D1760%26bih%3D855%26prmd%3Dimvns) on [this JP wiki](http://wiki.grovyle.net/pandora/), the times are as follows:

```
Morning     03:00-09:00
Noon        09:00-15:00
Evening     15:00-21:00
Night       21:00-03:00
```

And if you're looking for a list of when items can be found, [this other JP wiki](http://pandora.lostgamer.net/) lists the tower/time-specific items [here](http://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?hl=en&prev=/search%3Fq%3Dhttp://pandora.lostgamer.net/%26hl%3Den%26client%3Dfirefox-a%26hs%3DmrF%26rls%3Dorg.mozilla:en-US:official%26biw%3D1760%26bih%3D853%26prmd%3Dimvns&rurl=translate.google.ca&sl=ja&twu=1&u=http://pandora.lostgamer.net/E7-89-B9-E6-AE-8A-E7-B4-A0-E6-9D-90-.html&usg=ALkJrhiRTK7XijkJmuu-t3GRx1aUTF_g-Q). I'll probably put together a translation with the English names in a bit, but since you didn't ask for this yet, this much should be enough to get you going. All other items can be found at any time, but some only from specific towers (see [here](http://translate.google.ca/translate?hl=en&sl=ja&u=http://pandora.lostgamer.net/&ei=E-2ZT7_YNubK2AXu5pWyBw&sa=X&oi=translate&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCMQ7gEwAA&prev=/search%3Fq%3Dhttp://pandora.lostgamer.net/%26hl%3Den%26client%3Dfirefox-a%26hs%3DmrF%26rls%3Dorg.mozilla:en-US:official%26biw%3D1760%26bih%3D853%26prmd%3Dimvns) for more on this).